# Unknown "Icon?" file in Dropbox Stack

Tags: dock, dropbox

I have a shortcut to my Dropbox folder on my dock. Occasionally, a file called "Icon?" will appear when I click on the Dropbox folder on my dock, as shown below.

[image: Icon? file in Dropbox Stack]

Does anyone know why this file keeps appearing, and how to stop it from appearing again? I've tried deleting it, and it disappears for a while, but then eventually it comes back again. When I try opening the file, it just leads to a blank file in TextEdit. When I try to look directly in my Dropbox folder, by opening it directly in Finder, the file is nowhere to be found either.

If it helps, I am on the latest version of Sierra, on a mid-2012 rMBP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you recently turn on visibility for hidden files?
I see this file from time to time in my Dropbox too, however this file exists in every directory on macOS, it's just normally hidden. If you don't have hidden files turned on it's likely just an error with the Dropbox sync. See this really in-depth answer on Super User:
https://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop

Comment: I haven't made my hidden files visible, but I guess this explains things. Thanks!